# Set drawable's background image programmatically

Tags: android, button, background-image, android-button

I have a Button (btn). Is set the Button's style using a drawable:

```
btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mybtn_style);
```

This Button has some text. In some occasions I want to use an image instead of text.
Using the following:

```
if (useImagesinButtons==true){
   btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_myImage);
   btn.setText("");
}
```

replaces the style with the image (myImage).

But I don't want to change the overall style of the Button. I just want to set an image instead of text. I want to do that programmatically.

Could I change the drawable's background image before calling

```
btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mybtn_style);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (useImagesinButtons==true){
            btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_myImage);
        }
else{
btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mybtn_style);    
}
```

Comment: this replaces the style with an "empty" style with just the image. I don't want this. And I don't want to create a second style. I want to modify programmaticaly the style to include a picture

Answer (score 0):

->First set the button background in the XML file using " android:background" attribute.

-> then when ever you want text on button just set the text on button.

Comment: I don't want to modify the original style changing the xml because the same style is used in several buttons with different texts, and (when they have an image in background), with different images. I want to modify programmatically the existing style.

Comment: If you want to go with programming then setBackground() should work.

Comment: I can set the background that way. But I want to modify the background's image before I set it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change a style programmatically. However, you can create two different button instances for the two specific case you have. One text-only button and one with an image. Ofcourse you will be using one of the two at a time. Whenever the condition changes, you remove/add buttons.

Comment: I can't have 2 different styles (one with text and one with image) because as I commented in Tara's reply, the background images are not always the same. Are you sure I can't modify the style programmatically? I don't need to modify the origina l xml file.